# How to call dynamic function .testnet() or .mainnet() JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamic

I need to call a dynamic function based on whether we are migrating from a test environment to main net.

Here is the call that needs to be dynamic.

Assuming I am passing in a variable called environment that with be either:
Mainnet
Testnet

Result should mimic:

`client.forTestnet()`
or

`client.forMainney()`

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)?

Comment: That works!  Thank you!